# Programmatic builds using Maven 3 API

Tags: java, maven

Before you ask why I can just spawn a process to execute mvn, I wish to execute a Maven build through the Maven API, so that I can gather info on what goes on in the build, the artifacts produced etc etc. After depending on `org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0.4`, I have written the following method in an attempt to do such a thing:

```
public static void build(File directory, File pom) {
    Maven maven = new DefaultMaven();
    MavenExecutionRequest exec = new DefaultMavenExecutionRequest();
    exec.setBaseDirectory(directory);
    exec.setPom(pom);
    MavenExecutionResult result = maven.execute(exec);
    MavenProject proj = result.getProject();
    Artifact art = proj.getArtifact();
    System.out.println(art);
}
```

However this code fails at `maven.execute` due to null pointer exceptions. These null pointer exceptions are basically everywhere due to private fields in `DefaultMaven` not being initialized. They are all annotated with `@Required`, so I am guessing this is something to do with Plexus.

How can I successfully use Maven to execute such a build?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am looking to do something similar.

Comment: Nope I haven't solved it. Abandoned project.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the actual Maven embedding API:

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0/maven-embedder/apidocs/index.html

To see examples, look towards the open source of M2Eclipse.

Now, this component is not really very well-named. It's actually a convenience wrapper aimed at making an CLI. so, what you'll want to do is read the source of it.

Comment: That's not What I want either as it just outputs the build log, not a programmatic way to see all the results (artifacts). I have tried looking at Jenkins and m2e but the signal to noise is way too high.

Comment: Jenkins is the correct way of it, cause it offers all what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find the code relevant to creating such a maven instance though.

Answer (score 1):

Internet searches for how to do Maven builds using the API always lead me here, so I'd like to document how I've solved this issue. Do not use DefaultMaven directly. Instead, use the maven-verifier project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-verifier</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can use the Verifier class to build a project. The only catch is to pass the proper environment variable:

```
String baseDir = "<root path of the maven project you want to build>";
Map<String,String> env=new HashMap<>();
env.put("maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory", baseDir);

try {
    Verifier v=new Verifier(baseDir);
    v.executeGoals(Arrays.asList("clean","package"),env);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This resulted for me in the project being built, and a log.txt file being created in baseDir with the output of maven.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually used this API, looks interesting though.

I can't see where you are setting your goals to run?

You might need to call: `setGoals` on the Maven Execution Request.

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/DefaultMavenExecutionRequest.html#setGoals%28java.util.List%29

Comment: My question isn't really about that, at the moment the execution request is not even being executed, because every private field etc inside DefaultMaven is null, causing NPEs before it can be executed. EDIT: Added exec.setGoals(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"clean", "install"}));, but it still NPEs at at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:174), and virtually every other place.

Comment: Im wandering if this could be because you are not setting requiredp roperties. I just had a look at a couple of examples and they are all setting goals. I guess it would be interesting to see which properties are not initialized and see if you are supposed to be setting it or it should be initialized by default. Obv the error message is not helpful.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding, this isn't about my execution request but rather the DefaultMaven,  and why a private,  plexus annotated field is milk and not set anywhere. Take a look at the DefaultMaven source, specifically the finally block where the npe occurs.

Comment: Thats an assumption as execution request is the only thing you're passing through I wouldn't disregard it just yet. Whereabouts is the NPE?

Comment: Posted above, DefaultMaven, 174 in the finally block.  I also checked what was attempted to be returned with a debugger and the gathered exception list was filled with NPEs. I am 100% sure this is due to some plexus / pre loading magic needing to be done.