# execute a Maven build within a Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm working on a maven plugin that will, amongst other things, run `mvn compile` on the project.

I've tried adding this to my class that extends AbstractMojo (similar to https://github.com/rzymek/watcher-maven-plugin):

```
@Component
private Maven maven;
...
maven.execute(request);
```

That complains that maven is null. So then I tried:

```
Maven maven = new DefaultMaven();
maven.execute(request);
```

But that results in a NullPointerException at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:170) as described in this unanswered question [Programmatic builds using Maven 3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275841/programmatic-builds-using-maven-3-api)

I also tried

```
ClassRealm containerRealm = (ClassRealm) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
ContainerConfiguration cc = new DefaultContainerConfiguration().setName( "maven" ).setRealm( containerRealm ).setClassPathScanning( PlexusConstants.SCANNING_INDEX ).setAutoWiring( true );

DefaultPlexusContainer container = new DefaultPlexusContainer( cc );
Maven maven = (Maven) container.lookup( "org.apache.maven.Maven", "default" );
maven.execute(request);
```

But that threw a NoSuchElementException:

```
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
  role: org.apache.maven.Maven
  roleHint: default
```

I tried using the role hint from getPluginContext() with the same result.

Comment: can you explain why would you want to do mvn compile from a maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell maven to generate plugin description file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5346 -->
                <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ... -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```